# Getting the COUNT(*) value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using to following to count the number of rows in a table:

```
// Count rows
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$max = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

echo $max;
```

This echoes `array`. I understand why but I can't find how to get the value in this case. I've tried `$max[0]`. I don't understand how to reference the column in the array in this case.

Comment: `var_dump($max)` or `print_r($max)` should give you an idea of how to reference it.

Comment: You've tried `$max[0]` and then what?

Comment: @Jack It printed the same, 'array'. Like the solutions offered in the answer below

Comment: @Juicy try my edited answer

Comment: @crush you right , it should return one result not array , but i gave him to fetch this array by while in my edit. so i just wonder :)

Comment: Your query returns a 2 dimensional result set resource. It is a raw resource of table rows, which you've assigned to `$result`. When you execute `mysqli_fetch_row($result)` it gets the row at the current position, maintained by an internal iterator. Therefore, `$max`, based on your code provided, should be a 1 dimensional array. `$max[0]` should be returning the first column of the first row. Please provide the output of `print_r($max)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as counts FROM articles";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $max = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $max['counts'];
```

[some docs here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

EDIT:

```
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as counts FROM articles";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($max = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    echo $max['counts'];
    }
```

Comment: Why does he need to give `COUNT(*)` an alias for it to be available in the array? While this code is valid, it doesn't explain why the OP is having an issue. I think there is more to this problem than the OP has shown us. He shouldn't need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` at all.

Comment: yes , he is hiding some code , because it should work with `$max[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use MySQL PDO.

Try this:

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", username, password); 
    $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $errors = "There is no connection to the Server: localhost"; 
    }

$qry = $conn -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS counts FROM articles");

$qry -> execute();


while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

   $Total = $row['counts']; 

} 
echo $Total;
```